# Can I delete one item in JSON by jsonpath use golang

Tags: go, jsonpath

I have a json like this:

```json
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "doe",
    "age": 26,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
        "city": "Nara",
        "postalCode": "630-0192"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        }
    ]
}
```

And get a json path expression: $.phoneNumbers.*.type

How can I delete the keys by this expression in Go?

Comment: do you want to do this in pure go or use any lib? if you want to forward this JSON to some other place without the type just add a `-` json tag in your struct eg `Type string \`json:"-"\``. When you forward the JSON it will not be sent in the response

Comment: The json structure is made by user, so I cannot write the struct beforehand